# Amending this jquery to assign a random border colour to each link on page

Tags: jquery, arrays

I've a series of links on a page that I'd like to have different border colours on the bottom. Obviously I can style this up using CSS targeting the parent div, however I figured there must be an easier way to do this with jquery if I've an array of colour values.

I found this function, which adds the border on hover, but I'd like to change it so it add's it to the p a as the default. Hope this makes sense.

Not really sure how to go about this... any pointers would be great...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p a").hover(function(e) {
        var randomClass = getRandomClass();
        $(e.target).attr("class", randomClass);
    });
});

function getRandomClass() {
    //Store available css classes
    var classes = new Array("yellow", "pink", "green", "blue");

    //Give a random number from 0 to 5
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

    return classes[randomNumber];
}
</script>
```

---

Updated function

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
 $("p a").hover(function(e)
    {
        var randomClass = getRandomClass();
        $(e.target).attr("class", randomClass);
    });
});
function getRandomClass()
{
    //Store available css classes
    var classes = new Array("yellow", "pink", "green", "blue");

    //Give a random number from 0 to 5
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

    return classes[randomNumber];
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p a").each(function() {
        $(this).addClass(getRandomClass());
    });
});
```

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Comment: It adds the random colour only on hover.I want all the a's to have a border-bottom of 2px solid #XXX - and then a random border on hover as well.

Comment: Should they have random default colors or the same default color?

Comment: Random default colours chosen from the array above. The CSS has the classes in it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do it :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p a").each(function() {
        $(this).addClass(getRandomClass());
    });
});
```

uses [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over all `a` elements within `p` elements and adds a random class using [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Comment: Thank you! Is there a better way of combining the two than the updated functions above?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p a").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass(getRandomClass());
    });
    $("p a").hover(function(e) {
        var randomClass = getRandomClass();
        $(this).addClass(randomClass);
    },function(e){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
});
```

The problem was that the classes weren't getting removed, so the one that occurred in the css last would be the only one applied.

Comment: Hiya - it would probably help if i posted a link -http://www.pjephysiotherapy.co.uk/wp-content/themes/pjePhysiotherapy/index.html - your function works by adding a border to start, but the border is removed again until the user hovers back over. I tried to remove the removeClass biy, bu I'm obviously so rubbish at jQuery that it broke the whole thing :(